# When writing to the Windows Event Log, is it possible to create a custom link text for URLs?

Tags: c#, event-log

I'm just using the vanilla `EventLog.WriteEntry` method:

```
        EventLog.WriteEntry(EVENT_SOURCE, message, EventLogEntryType.Error, id);
```

Here's how the message shows up in the Event Log, with the links in the parenthesis working just fine, but it's ugly:

Example 1:

> Please contact us via email (mailto:some@example.com) or online (http://example.com).

Here's how the message shows up in the Event Log, with the HTML "markup", doesn't even handle it:

Example 2:

```
Please contact us via <a href="mailto:some@example.com">email</a> or <a href="http://example.com">online</a>.
```

This is how I would like the message to show up, but with "email" and "online" as the link texts:

Example 3:

> Please contact us via email or online.

I've tried the `<a href>...</a>` HTML tags with no success.

Comment: at first I would say because it's shown as straight text I don't think you can, but then it dawns on me that they show a bit of HTML don't they? What do you get if you put that? Does the link actually turn blue? I think that's all you can do, make it ugly.

Comment: Like Example 2 above shows, it doesn't parse and show HTML, instead it shows up with all the tags and markup (REALLY UGLY). They seem to find a URL and put a link on it automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported as far as I know.  If the ugly way is giving you clickable links, just stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

Beings the EventLog is not rendered as Html, I would have to say it doesn't work that way.